# Gnuplot - Vectors on 3d plot

Tags: gnuplot, visualization

I want to display vectors of optimization funtion on already created splot.

My code:

```
set xrange[1:4]
set yrange[2:5]
set zrange[2:6]

splot x+y-4, x+1-y, y-1-x, 10-x-y
```

[image]

And the gradients (vectors) are [2,3,1], [1,-1,1].

I would appreciate your help. 
(If you are able to create a linear function, I would also be happy :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include vectors as arrows, you could use the tool `set arrow`. For the two vectors you supplied:

```
set arrow 1 from 0,0,0 to 2,3,1
set arrow 2 from 0,0,0 to 1,-1,1
```

Of course you can change the appearance by applying any `arrowstyle` as it suits you.